# Entity Framework does not remove deleted table (EF6)

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a database-first model, if I "Update model from database" the wizard shows the new table and it is added to the model just fine.

If I delete that table and update again, the table shows on the 'Delete' tab of the wizard but after clicking 'finish' the object still shows on the edmx diagram and the table's class file is still in my project - am I missing something here?

Comment: Try 'Run Custom Tool' right clicking your edmx file

Comment: @Disha - there is no 'Run Custom Tool' option in the edmx context menu?

Comment: Are you right clicking your edmx file into Solution Explorer?

Comment: Yeah, the same place where I get to "Update model", no option there for running custom tools (I am using VS2013)

Answer (score 0):

Strangely it seems that this is by design, it means that for now you need to know the DB design changes and manage the EF model manually.

I have logged a feature request on the EF site.